# How to write *ngIf condition consists of square bracket notation

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a *ngIf condition which looks like

```
<i *ngIf="data && data.timeline["Initial Site Measurement Request"].ideal" class="fa fa-pencil ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="changeexpexteddate('Lead',data.lead_id,'Initial Site Measurement Request',data)"></i>
```

Basically when initial site measurement date's ideal date is not Present, icon should not be visible. I am getting Data in this format from BE only.
But using this square bracket notation on ngIf, I am getting Temlate Parse error in ngIf Condition.

Is there any alternate way to work this problem,.

Comment: use single quote inside: `<i *ngIf="data && data.timeline['Initial Site Measurement Request'].ideal" ...`

Comment: Oh God! This Actually Works. What is the diff b/w double and single quotes then

Comment: You were doubling up the quotes making it break `ngif="this["that"]"`